# git accidently pulled unfinished changes from anothers develop branch before pushing to origin

Tags: git

Had committed changes to my develop branch, ready to promote to origin, and before I did, I pulled for another devs develop (not a branch), into my develop to look at something, then forgot I did and pushed to origin which moved both my finished commits and the other developers unfinished commits.  Now I don't know what to do to restore origin. I reverted to my last commit before pulling in the other dev, and then created a new branch.  How can I revert origin to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new branch from your last commit stash or you can push your changes from that stash in your dev branch using -f option.

Comment: Using `-f` is dangerous as you may force push multiple branches. It's better to use an explicit `+` before each branch name to force push.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git push origin +branch` to force push only this branch.